# Dynamic dropdown options with Vuetify and Firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using nuxt, vuetify and firebase (cloud firestore for database) to build a contractor's database app. There will be a multiple of scope of works (SOW) & specializations for contractor to choose from when they filling a form.

For 1 scope of work, there will be multiple choices of specialization. So, whenever the user choose a SOW on the first select option, there will be just a limited number of specialization to choose from on the second select option that related to that particular SOW. After picking the specialization, the 3rd select option will auto display the code assigned to that specialization. All the data for SOWs & specializations is get from firestore database.

I have no problem to load the data from firestore for all 3 options. It just that it not do the dynamic dropdown the way I wanted.

I already referred to https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/Lgxrcc5p/ but cant really working out the solution. Is there an a way to do this?

Image of the 3 select options here : [After select scope, nothing happen on the 2nd select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D64N.png)

Thanks!

Here is my template code using vuetify v-select

```
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                      <v-select
                        :items="scope"
                        item-text="scope"
                        v-model="editedItem.scope"
                        label="Scope"
                        @click="listofscope"
                      ></v-select>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                      <v-select
                        :items="special"
                        item-text="specialization"
                        v-model="editedItem.specialization"
                        :disabled="listofspecialization.length == 0"
                        label="Specialization"
                        @click="listofspecialization"    
                      ></v-select>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                      <v-select
                        :items="special"
                        item-text="code"
                        v-model="editedItem.code"
                        :disabled="listofspecialization.length == 0"
                        label="Code"
                        @click="listofspecialization"
                      ></v-select>
                    </v-col>
```

Here is my script part

```
data: () => ({
    // ..my other codes

    scope: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      scope: '',
    },
    defaultItem: {
      scope: '',
    },

    special: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      specialization: '',
      code: '',
    },
    defaultItem: {
      specialization: '',
      code: '',
    },
)}
```

```
    listofscope() {
      this.scope = []
      db
        .collection('Scope of Works')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            this.scope.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          })
          if (this.listofscope.length > 0) {
            this.listofspecialization = [this.scope]
          }
          console.log(this.scope)
        })
    },

    listofspecialization() {
      this.special = []
      db
        .collectionGroup("Specialization")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            this.special.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
          })
          if (this.listofspecialization.length > 0) {
            this.code = [this.scope][this.specialization]
          }
          console.log(this.special)
        })
```

Comment: Are you using watchers to watch the changes. Because as your code says, you used ``@click`` which only listen to the click on the ``v-select``. It does not listen to the changes. Try using ``@change`` instead.

Comment: Hi Mani, apologies for the late reply. Using watchers solved the issue. Thanks for the suggestions :))

Answer (score 1):

I put my answer here in case if someone had the same problem with me. Yes, using watchers solved the problem.

Now, whenever I pick a scope, a limited choice of specialization will list out. Then, when I picked a specialization, it will automatically display the code assigned to that particular specialization.

Here's how I do it:

1. My HTML part:

```
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="scopes"
                                            item-text="scope"
                                            v-model="editedItem.scope"
                                            label="Scope"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="specializationFiltered"
                                            item-text="specialization"
                                            v-model="editedItem.specialization"
                                            label="Specialization"
                                            return-object
                                            :disabled="specializations.length == 0"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="codes"
                                            item-text="code"
                                            v-model="editedItem.specialization.code"
                                            label="Code"
                                            :disabled="true"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
```

2. My script part

```
        watch: {
            "editedItem.scope"(newVal) {
                this.specializationFiltered = [];
                if (this.editedItem.scope) {
                firestore
                    .collection("Scope of Works")
                    .doc(this.editedItem.scope)
                    .collection("Specialization")
                    .get()
                    .then(querySnapshot => {
                        console.log(querySnapshot);
                        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            console.log(doc.data());
                            this.specializationFiltered.push(doc.data());
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

Thanks :))