# Dynamic select option is not working anymore after change to new firebase project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

This is a follow-up question from a question that I asked and answered before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762698/16136444

In summary, if I pick a choice on the 1st v-select, it will only display limited choices on the 2nd v-select, which are related to the first choice that I made on the 1st v-select. Then, after choices are made on the 2nd v-select, it will auto-generate and display the code assigned to that 2nd choice on the 3rd v-select.

Before it was successfully done on my testing firebase project and it works and it still is. But after I created a new firebase project and do the same thing, it did not work out.

1. Old firestore collection on my testing project

- Scope of Works > All docs contain scope value > Specialization > docs containing specialization & code

[image: old firestore on my testing project 1]
[image: old firestore on my testing project 2]

1.1 - my old v-select: as you can see it display some choices on 2nd v-select (top right) after choose an option on 1st v-select.
[image: v-select on old firebase project]

2. New firestore collection created for production project
   [image: new firestore on my production project 1]
   [image: new firestore on my production project 2]

2.1- new v-select on new firebase project (not displaying anything on the 2nd v-select
[image: v-select on new firebase project]

2.2- My firefox console also not displaying anything
[image: firefox console not displaying data, just this]

So, the only thing that is changed is I removed spacing & use PascalCase for the name of the collection and documents. Other than it is all just the same. So now I used `.collection("ScopeOfWork")` (new) instead of `.collection("Scope of Works")`(old) to read from firestore

What could possibly be wrong with it? Any advice?

Edited (16/12/2021):
add screenshot of both v-select on my old and new firebase project.
add a screenshot of my firefox console.

Comment: What do you mean when you say ```it did not work out```? do you get some error message?

Comment: Hi @ZeenathSN, apologize for the late reply & for not explaining it in detail. I added screenshots 1.1 & 2.1 that show what is supposed to work but not working properly on the new one. (2nd v-select should display choices after choices on 1st v-select is picked). Firefox console also does not display any data just ```Object { _firestore: {…}, _delegate: {…} }``` everytime 2nd v-select is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after a while.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762698/16136444

The above link shows how I code so that I can do the dynamic select option. It is a question that I asked and answered previously on StackOverflow.

Regarding why it does not work when I create a new project is that the name of the document is not the same as the data value inside the document.

I am using watchers to do dynamic select options of my form.

```
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="scopes"
                                            item-text="scope"
                                            v-model="editedItem.scope"
                                            label="Scope"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="specializationFiltered"
                                            item-text="specialization"
                                            v-model="editedItem.specialization"
                                            label="Specialization"
                                            return-object
                                            :disabled="specializations.length == 0"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
                                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="5">
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="codes"
                                            item-text="code"
                                            v-model="editedItem.specialization.code"
                                            label="Code"
                                            :disabled="true"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
```

```
        watch: {
            "editedItem.scope"(newVal) {
                this.specializationFiltered = [];
                if (this.editedItem.scope) {
                firestore
                    .collection("ScopeOfWork")
                    .doc(this.editedItem.scope)
                    .collection("Specialization")
                    .get()
                    .then(querySnapshot => {
                        console.log(querySnapshot);
                        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                            console.log(doc.data());
                            this.specializationFiltered.push(doc.data());
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

I can make it work only when the name of docs is the same as the value inside the docs itself.

If I have value `scope: Metal Works` inside the document, The document need to be named `Metal Works` same as the values inside it. I wish I can explain it in detail but my knowledge is still at a low-level. But I do realise it comes from the way I called the data from firestore `firestore.collection("ScopeOfWork").doc(this.editedItem.scope)`

I've not changed anything from the codes except the name of the collections and documents only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having extra space or using PascalCase should change the behavior.

Since you didn't show the complete code, it's hard for me to verify if everything is set up correctly. One thing that could be causing the issue might be the difference between "MetalWorks" vs "Metal Works". i.e. the correct specialization is not selected due to the space difference, as that's the only difference I can see from the screenshots shared. I think for next steps, you should verify your code or post the complete comparison of the code for further investigation. Another thing to try is instead of trying to render on the v-select page(website), can you just double check if there are results returned from their Firestore script/query (i.e. firestore.collection.doc.get() part). If you are able to get results from the script, then you will need to investigate the html part. If the get() request fails, then you will need to investigate the query part and make sure the firestore query could fetch the correct resources.

Comment: Hi there, just to update you. After a while, I managed to make it work. The name of the document need to be the same with the value inside. If the data inside the doc is ```scope: Metal Works```. The document also needs to be named "Metal Works". Probably because the way I called the data from firestore (```.doc(this.editedItem.scope)```). I will put more explanation of it with codes as answer